# How do you connect MySQL to Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am unable to get MySQL working with Spring boot.

I created a database in MySQL titled todo4db and then ran the compiler with the below code.

I then checked whether tables were generated in MySQL but shows empty set.

I have no idea how to solve this issue as I have been working on this for hours.

Please help.

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tododb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

Spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Todo.java

```
package com.assignment.todolistapp.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String todoName;

    public Todo(String todoName) {
        this.todoName = todoName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTodoName() {
        return todoName;
    }

    public void setTodoName(String todoName) {
        this.todoName = todoName;
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.assignment'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: couple bits of missing information make this hard to figure out.  what package is the @SpringBootApplication in?  What starters are you including?  Maybe check this for a step-by-step (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: @jameygraham Added more of my files. I`m using IntelliJ and Spring Initializr.

Comment: Your URL uses `tododb` whilst in your explanation you mention `todo4db` those are different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings work for me:

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  database:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_dvdrental
    username: user_dvdrental
    password: changeit
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    generate-ddl: false
```

Make sure you change `Postgres` settings with `MySQL`'s.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/yiiu?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8
    username: root
    password: 123123
  jpa:
    database: mysql
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate.format_sql: true
```

I configure it this way.